# Is it possible to set up Azure as a publisher for Pull Replication to an on-premise database?

Tags: sql-server, replication, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2017

I am trying to set up Pull Replication from an Azure database to an on-premise database.  I have set up the on-premise database as the distributor but when I try to establish a subscription to the Azure database I get an error, see below.

```
TITLE: New Subscription Wizard
------------------------------

SQL Server could not retrieve the list of databases for server 'nyrstar-prod-01.database.windows.net'.

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=14.0.17254.0&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.CreateSubWizardErrorSR&EvtID=CantGetDatabaseList&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

------------------------------

Could not find stored procedure 'sp_get_distributor'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2812)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=12.00.0600&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=2812&LinkId=20476

-------------------------------
-------------------------------
ALL ADVANCED INFORMATION
-------------------------------
-------------------------------

===================================

SQL Server could not retrieve the list of databases for server 'nyrstar-prod-01.database.windows.net'. (New Subscription Wizard)

------------------------------
For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=14.0.17254.0&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.CreateSubWizardErrorSR&EvtID=CantGetDatabaseList&LinkId=20476

===================================

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.GetExecuteReader(SqlCommand command)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteReader(String sqlCommand, SqlCommand& command)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.ReplicationServer.RefreshGetDistributor()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.PageChoosePublication.EnumDatabases(ReplicationSqlConnection sqlConn)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.PageChoosePublication.LoadDatabases(ReplicationSqlConnection publisherConn, String selectedDBName, String selectedPubName, Boolean isHeterogeneous)

===================================

Could not find stored procedure 'sp_get_distributor'. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

------------------------------
For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=12.00.0600&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=2812&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
Server Name: nyrstar-prod-01.database.windows.net
Error Number: 2812
Severity: 16
State: 62
Line Number: 1


------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.ExecuteTSql(ExecuteTSqlAction action, Object execObject, DataSet fillDataSet, Boolean catchException)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.GetExecuteReader(SqlCommand command)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time, replication is only supported **from** on-prem **to** SQL Database, and it has to be **push** replication.  See here:

[Replication to SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/replication-to-sql-database?view=sql-server-2017#limitations)

> **Supported Configurations:**
>
> - The SQL Server can be an instance of SQL Server running on-premises or an instance of SQL Server running in an Azure virtual machine in
>     the cloud
> - SQL Database must be a push subscriber of a SQL Server publisher.
> - The distribution database and the replication agents cannot be placed on SQL Database.

You may want to consider Managed Instances to get around this.  See [Replication with SQL Database Managed Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/replication-with-sql-database-managed-instance?view=sql-server-2017) for details.